# Jewish dervishes and "Darkeihem"

Tags: halacha, minhag, gentiles, symbols-symbology, hukot-hagoyim

This photo shows [a pair of Jewish](http://touba.tumblr.com/post/10216972348/jewish-dervishes-agha-jaan-darvish-and-his) [dervishes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dervish).  It has been going around the Jewish-oriented pages of the internet and social media lately, and it got me wondering: would this be a problem of following the ways of non-Jews, especially religiously-oriented practices?
[image: This photo]

Related: [May a Jew be a Freemason?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22905/5)

Comment: All I see is people with long hair and funny clothes holding hatchets and books. Can you [edit] in what these people do that you suspect may be in error?

Comment: I also read this article, which prompted the same question, see http://kavvanah.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/jewish-sufi-dervishes-1922/

Comment: @msh210, I linked to the Wikipedia page about Dervishes. I'll add more detail later, Beli Neder.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dervish) defines a Dervish as

> “someone treading a Sufi Muslim ascetic path or "Tariqah", known for
>   their extreme poverty and austerity.”

[Rabbi Buchwald](http://rabbibuchwald.njop.org/) in an article for Re’eh 5773-2013, says

> In this week’s parasha, parashat Re’eh, we learn of the Biblical
>   command that the People of Israel must destroy all vestiges of pagan
>   and polytheistic worship, whenever they are found.
>
> The Torah, in Deuteronomy 12:2 reads,  “You shall utterly destroy all
>   the places where the nations that you shall possess worshipped their
>   gods: on the high mountains and on the hills, and under every leafy
>   tree.” The Torah, in Deuteronomy 12:3, follows with specific demands
>   that the Israelites break apart all the pagan altars, smash their
>   pillars, and burn their sacred trees in fire. The idolatrous carved
>   images must be cut down, and the Israelites shall obliterate their
>   names from that place.

So if any form of idolatry is involved, it will be obviously forbidden.

[This blog](http://jihadiyehudi.blogspot.co.uk/2011_07_01_archive.html) tries to explain “Chukas Hagoy”.

> The Torah warns us to avoid “chukkat ha goyim” the “statutes of the
>   nations.” As a holy nation, separated by the unique discipline of the
>   Torah we are sternly warned to avoid gentile practices. The law is
>   complicated and this is just meant to be a quick review to expose my
>   thinking.
>
> the prohibition, says Rashi, applies particularly to Non-Jewish
>   practices that reflect corruption, idolatrous superstitions or such
>   things as attending “theaters or stadiums.” We are told elsewhere that
>   the prohibition is on attending theaters and stadiums is one of the
>   first and few laws that a potential convert must be taught. This
>   refers to the Roman stadiums which were the site of violent gladiator
>   games. Jews were and are forbidden to enjoy entertainments which focus
>   on degrading human beings and torturing animals.
>
> In general, these prohibitions distance Jews from things that are not
>   in keeping with Jewish values.
>
> By contrast, the Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh De’ah), the most authoritative
>   code of Jewish law concludes that if the custom does not promote
>   idolatrous behavior and/or is viewed as a "dignified act", then no
>   such prohibition of "chukat HaGoy" exists. While there may yet be
>   other halachic prohibitions that would restrain a Jew from taking up
>   such a practice for themselves, there is surely no reason why we
>   should discourage others from following it. On the contrary, I believe
>   the obligations of Jewish spiritual citizenship may demand that we
>   encourage it. That is where my thoughts begin.

Being a Dervish does seem to have its origin in “ gentile practices”, (Sufi Muslim) and I suggest that there is not a tradition (for others than special individuals) of asceticism in Judaism; therefore it seems that these would be “things that are not in keeping with Jewish values”.

Comment: jewish sufism is the ways of the prophets according to rabbeinu abrohom ban harambam zl and in general most if not all of the 7assidei safarad in the middle ages

Comment: -1 for many reasons: as @MoriDoweedhYaa3qob wrote, asceticism has a long and valued tradition in Judaism, and many believe that that's the way of the Torah, meant for everyone, not just prophets, and I don't see the relevance to idolatry. Do you think Muslims are idolaters? Do these practices have anything to do with idolatry or immorality? Is anything not in the Torah automatically not in accordance with Jewish values? Wearing a white coat to show that you're a doctor isn't a "Jewish value"